# Javascript function call by string name

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function defined like this

```
function is_mandatory(string){
     if(string.length > 0 )
 return true;   
}
```

Now, i am trying to call the function defined as a sting name

```
var is_mandatory; 

is_mandatory("Check");
```

But, this returns an error saying variable is not a function. How can I call the function from a string name.

Cheers!

Comment: You have defined variable with same name as method and that's why you are getting such an error. Try changing variable name of `var is_mandatory;`.

Comment: You're not trying to call the function defined as a string name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Your definition of is_mandatory will return `undefined` if you pass in a string whose length === 0. I don't think this is intended.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
function is_mandatory(str){
     return (str.length > 0 );
}

is_mandatory("Check");
```

You do not have to declare `var` for `is_mandatory`

Answer (score 0):

You are re-defining `is_mandatory` as an undefined variable when you run this code:

```
var is_mandatory;
```

But I don't think that is your intent. Just delete that `var` line completely.

Comment: No problem.  They are similar concepts, just different actual values.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is declared in the window's scope you can do this:

```
function is_mandatory(str){
    if(window[str].length > 0 )
        return true;   
}
```

[**JS Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7AqJN/)

Answer (score -2):

Initialize you variable with your function, and then try to call it.

```
var is_mandatory = is_mandatory;

is_mandatory("Check");
```